# An Animated Short Film About Horses Living In Heaven

Tags: identify-this-movie

A long time ago (about 16 years ago) I watched a large portion of an animated short film. Thinking about it now, I'm not sure it was suitable for an audience of 6-8 year olds. I still have some very vivid images and clearly remember that I didn't get to watch its end and for many years I've been eager to see it, but I wasn't able to come up with the correct Google keywords combination to find it.

The following are the information I still remember about it.

- It's an animated colored cartoon, not fancy 3D animation.
- It's basically about horses that live in a heavenly place, surrounded with clouds and it appears to be some sort of floating island.
- The horses are portrayed mostly with a Homosapien posture (standing up on two limbs).
- The horses engage in daily-life activities, one horse is pictured practicing [Blacksmithery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacksmith).
- **Main plot idea:** At some point one of the horses suddenly stops his activity and then he walks and appears to be asleep but with open and strangely colored eyes while other horses stop their activities and appear to be sad about him. The other horses avoid looking at him by covering their eyes with their hands. The horse continues walking until he reaches a pit in which he throws himself. The fall takes a long time during which the horse is morphing into strange shapes and then he reaches a [pupal state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupa) and as he continues to fall he comes out as some kind of [Batoidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batoidea) then he exists from the bottom of the floating island where he flies in the heavenly space.
- I'm 95% certain it didn't have any dialogue, apart from random sounds the horses made to express surprise or sadness.
- I watched it some time between 1995 and 1997.

I hope I was able to provide enough information to make identification possible.

**Update:** After [jlmcdonald's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/4555/2131) I watched the film again, I was very shocked. I think the whole thing (watching the film long time ago when I was young and then watching it again) was a very interesting experience. I was surprised how little I remembered about the graphics/colors (I had a totally different image in my head) and how some scenes were vividly engraved in my memory. I was also surprised to see that I, indeed, watched the whole film the first time I saw it, but for some reason I thought otherwise. It turned out they weren't actually horses, but at the age of 6-7 that was the best I could come up with.

Comment: was it a finnish short film?

Comment: @oers, no I don't think so. I have a feeling it _might_ be French, though there was no dialogue.

Comment: is it from Disney? Can you remember?

Comment: @Hakkı, I'm almost certain (99%) It's not from Disney.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is *[Skywhales](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0228867/)* the movie you're after? Here is a clip on YouTube:

Comment: Also I'm very curious, did you see the film before? Or did you Google it? If so, please tell me the keywords you used.

Comment: It was all Google; I'd never seen it before last night. I started off searching on the upright horse image, as it seemed the most distinctive and the most likely to show up. But when that came up empty, I tried to think like a 6 year old and realized that it might not be actual horses, but animated characters that just looked horse-like. Also, I focused on the floating island, as that's another distinctive image that would likely be mentioned somewhere. My search string, then, was "animated short horse people floating island" -- the second result was Skywhales (the first was your question).

Comment: @jlmcdonald please edit how you came to find this question into your answer.  Comments are meant to help add clarity to a question or answer, and your comment should most defiantely be in your answer.